# Cultural and geographical phrases usage

Tags: modismos

> Aprovechando que la Pisuerga pasa por Valladolid.

I wonder if this phrase is only used in Spain. I mean can it be used in other Latin-American countries? Also, for Spanish learners writing exam essays or in conversations anywhere in the world is it ok to use? Is it odd, outside of a geographical area?
I ask this due to the geographical nature of the phrase, Pisuerga being a river in Spain.

I believe, "el quinto pino" can be used anywhere even though it is from Madrid.

I have the same question for a cultural phrase "tener un saque que ni Zamora". Zamora, I believe, was a general, so I wonder, culturally, can it be used in a broad general sense?
I think the 2 phrases are related to my question in relation to Spanish geographical and cultural phrases.

Comment: One would assume your teacher has a high level of culture, even if a term is not used in some country. If I used a common British one in the States, I'd expect my teacher to get it. In any case, this question is about opinions, not facts.

Comment: Por lo menos en Colombia NO, ninguno; se nota que son modismos usados en España

Comment: @alvalongo Justo lo que apuntaba en mi respuesta. Supongo que en Colombia usais expresiones distintas. Sería interesante que añadieras algunas de ellas. Lo de Zamora se usa para una persona que es capaz de beber o comer mucho. Lo del Pisuerga podría resumirse como "No tiene nada que ver pero ..." o "Cambiando totalmente de tema ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "el Pisuerga" because it's "el río Pisuerga".

It's just my opinion but I think that "aprovechando que el Pisuerga pasa por Valladolid" can be used in any region of Spain but probably it won't be understood in any other Spanish speaking country. Probably each region/country has got its own idiom reflecting a similar meaning.

[Zamora](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricardo_Zamora) was a goalkeeper. Probably that phrase is not even common in Spain anymore, it's pretty old-fashioned. Take into account that Zamora started playing professionally around 1920.

Not sure about its real meaning, it's the first time that I saw it but it seems a pun of words using two different meanings of "[tener buen saque](https://dle.rae.es/saque)": (1) being able to drink or eat a lot and (2) having a good goal kick.

As I said, pretty old-fashioned, probably you can use it in any region of Spain and most people would understand it but just because football is omni-present here and because the best goalkeeper of the year in our main league is awarded the "[Trofeo Zamora](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trofeo_Zamora)" named after him. So most people would do the "connections". What I stated about the other idiom is valid for this one as well: not used in other countries, they have got their our idioms for saying that someone can drink/eat a lot.

Comment: ok, thanks, I understand. I wonder, is it strange to use them  in Spanish conversations /essays if you are a non-native speaker not even in Spain?

Comment: @Bluelion7 I think that using idioms in a conversation is a good sign for a non-native speaker. But you need to be aware of which ones you can use depending on the country. As I said those two in particular don't seem universal for Spanish speaking countries.

Comment: @Bluelion7 Do you know the idiom: "kill two birds with one stone". Its equivalent in Spanish is pretty similar: "matar dos pájaros de un tiro". I think that that one is understandable in any Spanish speaking country.

Comment: @Bluelion7 I missed the part about using it in exam essays. Nowadays your teacher can google that expression and if it's valid in any Spanish speaking country and its meaning is valid in the context that you used it, it should be ok for you to use it.

Comment: @RubioRic, y a todas estás que significa "Aprovechando que la Pisuerga pasa por Valladolid"? sugiero agregarlo a la respuesta.

Comment: @alvalongo EL Pisuerga, EL Pisuerga. El Pisuerga es un río. "Se suele decir cuando se va a hablar o alguien comienza a hablar de algo que no tiene nada que ver que lo que se estaba tratando" https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/5030180/0/orrigen-expresion-aprovechando-pisuerga-pasa-valladolid/